# Wny it does not give all positive numbers in the string? Regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

I don't understand why it only gives 125, the first number only, why it does not give all positive numbers in that string? My goal is to extract all positive numbers.

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"^[+]?\d+")

text = "125 -898 8969 4788 -2 158 -947 599"

matches = pattern.finditer(text)

for match in matches:
    print(match)
```

Comment: Because your regex only matches at the beginning of the string thanks to the start of string anchor: `^`. It also wouldn't actually match only positive integers if you remove it because it would match the `898` after skipping the `-` in front of it.

Comment: The other numbers in the negative are included. It does not separate all the positives.

Answer (score 7):

Try using the regular expression

```
-\d+|(\d+)
```

Disregard the matches. The strings representing non-negative integers are saved in capture group 1.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gcNyd2/1)

The idea is to match but not save to a capture group what you don't want (negative numbers), and both match and save to a capture group what you do want (non-negative numbers).

The regex attempts to match `-\d+`. If that succeeds the regex engine's internal string pointer is moved to just after the last digit matched. If `-\d+` is not matched an attempt is made to match the second part of the alternation (following `|`). If `\d+` is matched the match is saved to capture group 1.

Any plus signs in the string can be disregarded.

For a fuller description of this technique see [The Greatest Regex Trick Ever](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html). (Search for `"Tarzan"|(Tarzan)` to get to the punch line.)

Comment: Thank you for the link as well +1 from me

Answer (score 4):

The following pattern will only match non negative numbers:

```
pattern = re.compile("(?:^|[^\-\d])(\d+)")

pattern.findall(text)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
['125', '8969', '4788', '158', '599']
```

Comment: yes exactly - it returns a list with all the captured matches

Comment: Very nice answer!

Answer (score 4):

For the sake of completeness another idea by use of [`\b`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) and a [lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
\b(?<!-)\d+
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/1aeQvJ/1)

Answer (score 3):

Your pattern `^[+]?\d+` is anchored at the start of the string, and will give only that match at the beginning.

Another option is to assert a whitspace boundary to the left, and match the optional `+` followed by 1 or more digits.

```
(?<!\S)\+?\d+\b
```

- `(?<!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary to the left
- `\+?` Match an optional `+`
- `\d+\b` Match 1 or more digits followed by a word bounadry

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QUKojX/1)

Answer (score 0):

Use , to sperate the numbers in the string.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).